# how to select rows based on 1st rows display prefered value and then display all values in table

Tags: mysql

I need to query a table to return rows and I am not able to query correctly. Here is my table view:

```
Id      Name  
1        a  
2        b  
3        c  
4        d  
5        e
```

Result set will return:

```
Id      Name  
3        c  
2        b  
1        a  
4        d  
5        e
```

Comment: what is your logic to get this result? explain

Comment: and the query ? The problem?  You dont like the order ? just polishing the crystal ball now ;-)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Id;` ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports tricky order by *some of the field values*.
This can be achieved by using `FIELD` function in `ORDER BY` clause.

***Example***:

```
SELECT id, name FROM my_table
 ORDER BY FIELD( id, 1, 2, 3 ) DESC;
```

***Refer to***:

- [Ordering by specific field values with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)
- [MySQL: Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html)